# Could I read lines from a C++ socket using Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, sockets, ubuntu

I wonder if I could read several lines from a C++ socket using Ubuntu?

Please note that every line is to be used for a different purpose (e.g. maybe the first is used as a string and the second as a char array).

I.e. Could I put those two lines directly after each other without encountering any problem?

```
read(socketFileDescriptor, buffer1, BUFFER_SIZE);
read(socketFileDescriptor, buffer2, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Thanks in advance,
Regards,

Comment: Sockets are part of an operating system, not a programming language; it doesn't make sense to talk about a "C++ socket". Ubuntu is an operating system, not a programming language; it doesn't make sense to talk about doing this "using Ubuntu".

Comment: You could certainly execute this code without a problem, *but* there's no guarantee that the data you receive from a call to `read` will correspond to a "line".

Comment: hhahaahaha,
Dear @duskwuff, I know that. The 'Read' expression is not used in Visual C++ :) I put Ubuntu in order to ease up the topics classification

Comment: Dear @JerryCoffin, would you please explain why there is no guarantee.

Comment: @nour: `read` just reads "raw" data. It pretty much ignores what's in the data it's reading. If you write two lines of (say) 80 bytes apiece on one end, those could come through as a single TCP packet on the other end, and `read` could read the entire 160 bytes together (assuming your BUFFER_SIZE >= 160). Conversely, if (for example) your BUFFER_SIZE==100, then you might get all the first line and part of the second in the first read, and the remainder of the second in the second call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `read` twice in sequence without any problem in itself.

What you get from each call may not correspond to a single line of input though. `read` basically just does "raw" reading, just about like it does when reading from a file on disk--if data is available, it will read as much data as necessary to fill the buffer you gave it (up to the size you specified).

TCP treats data as a stream, so data you pass to two (or more) separate calls to `write` could end up being put into a single packet and transmitted together. On the receiving end, all that data could be read by a single call to `read`--or, depending on the buffer size you pass, it might read only part of one, or might read all of the first and part of the second, etc.

If you want to read the input as "lines", you could (for one example) create a stream buffer that reads data from a socket, and create an iostream object that parses data from that buffer to read lines. This initially seems attractive to many people (it did to me, anyway), but has never worked out very well, at least for me. Iostreams basically assume a synchronous protocol, but sockets are mostly asynchronous. Trying to treat sockets as synchronous tends to lead to more problems rather than to solutions.